# How to manipulate GROUP BY rows with ANSISQL?

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

```
SELECT COMMISSION_PCT, COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY COMMISSION_PCT;
```

The result of is:

```
COMMISSION_PCT, COUNT(*)
NULL,72
0.15,5
0.35,3
0.40,1
0.30,7
0.20,7
0.25,6
0.10,6
```

Here, I need to add 0.25 to 0.2 row, and 0.35 to 0.3, but I'm curious how to do this.

Here is the result I want:

```
COMMISSION_PCT, COUNT(*)
NULL,72
0.15,5
0.40,1
0.30,10
0.20,13
0.10,6
```

Comment: I'm curious why you want an "ANSI SQL" solution, given that there is probably no database that is 100% compliant.

Comment: Whats the logic for "I need to add 0.25 to 0.2 row, and 0.35 to 0.3". There has to be a generic rule. You can follow below answer but i think a generic rule will help to create a generic sql.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI SQL compliant solution:

```
select commission_pct, count(*)
from
(
    select case when commission_pct in (0.25, 0.35) then commission_pct - 0.05
                else commission_pct
           end as commission_pct
    from employees
) e
group by commission_pct
```

The following feature outside Core SQL-2016 is used: *F591, Derived tables*

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when commission_pct in (0.20, 0.25) then 0.2
             when commission_pct in (0.30, 0.35) then 0.3
             else commission_pct
        end) as commission_pct,
       count(*)
from employees e
group by (case when commission_pct in (0.20, 0.25) then 0.2
               when commission_pct in (0.30, 0.35) then 0.3
               else commission_pct
          end);
```

Comment: Just a note, ANSI SQL does not allow the case expression in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @jarlh . . . Are you sure?  It doesn't allow the alias, so a subquery is necessary?

Comment: Yes, very sure, the subquery is required. But, of course, most products allow expressions in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @jarlh . . . I think almost every database does (including ancient versions of Oracle) -- although there is one out there (may Hive) that requires the alias and doesn't allow an expression.